# Take a Little Trip With Me!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

On my way to work this morning, I was listening to SiriusXM and a song came on that always cheers me up. Not sure if it's for one reason, or another (spoilers, so I won't go into detail until an answer is accepted); however, in the spirit of my previous riddle, can you guess this song? Should be simple enough!

> I'm stuck here in traffic, that couldn't go slower;
>
> I could go faster, while riding my mower.
>
> I could take the next exit, I know every street;
>
> What is the point, more traffic I'll meet.
>
> If the insanity continues, I'll run out of gas;
>
> I wish it would move, just pick up, go fast.

**Hint**:

> If finding me has you stuck in a slump; my genre is originally known as the funk.

**Hint**:

> Look to the riddle, for it will tell; the words that you seek, aren't hidden that well.

**Hint**:

> Even the title, can be seen as the same; this song is part of, the Grammy Hall of Fame.

As a bonus question, do you know what this song was written about?

Comment: Is the trivia tag needed to solve this?

Comment: Could be, it fits into that category also, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Can we get a hint as to the genre (of this one and the other song riddle)? I have no idea where to begin looking! XD

Comment: Updated both riddles with a genre!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this song

> [Low Rider, by War](https://genius.com/War-low-rider-lyrics)? It's a fantastic song (and thankfully one from an era that I know haha!)

Apparently,

> thanks to that link, it's about hydraulically hot-rodding classic cars! Also, it's the theme song to [the George Lopez show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lopez_(TV_series))!

Comment: Hence I didn't want to add too many hints! That was too fast... :( Great shot!

Comment: In all honesty, if it wasn't from 1955-1985, I had zero chance of guessing it correctly haha! Love the song though!

Comment: It is a fantastic song! Surprised my first one hasn't been guessed, though it isn't as mainstream! Especially to my generation!